# Importing CSV into MySQL (WAMP), no data appears in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, csv

I am trying to create a web page that allows end-users to upload a CSV file to a database. I thought I had this mapped out, and the page behaves like the data goes through. When I check my table, however, it's empty.

I have a guid trigger for table[0] that does not exist in the CSV, so I am trying to fill data in starting at table[1]. I know my connection is solid because I am able to query data from the database on a different web page.

Here is my code, after establishing the connection to the database:

```
        if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {

    //get the csv file
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database
    do {
    if ($data[1]) {
        mysqli_query("INSERT INTO bnsf1 (offline, unit, commodity, shipper, origin, originState, current, currentState, estimatedArrival, carType, destination, destinationState, CP_dateTime, waybillNumber, equipmentLength) VALUES
            (
                '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                '".addslashes($data[3])."',
                '".addslashes($data[4])."',
                '".addslashes($data[5])."',
                '".addslashes($data[6])."',
                '".addslashes($data[7])."',
                '".addslashes($data[8])."',
                '".addslashes($data[9])."',
                '".addslashes($data[10])."',
                '".addslashes($data[11])."',
                '".addslashes($data[12])."',
                '".addslashes($data[13])."',
                '".addslashes($data[14])."',
                '".addslashes($data[15])."'
            )
        ");
            }
        } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
    //

    //redirect
    header('Location: form1.php?success=1'); die;

    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Import a CSV File</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php if (!empty($_GET[success])) { echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br><br>"; } //generic success notice ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
  Choose your file: <br />
  <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for looking!

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($data)` inside the do-while loop? Also, why use a do-while loop instead of a normal while loop? On your first iteration, nothing will happen as $data[1] equates to false.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the suggestion. `var_dump($data)` shows me all of my data but it looks awful, but it does tell me that my data is at least going somewhere. Regarding the loop, I'm not sure I follow you. Won't `$data[0]` overwrite my guid values?

Comment: Go search for a proper tutorial that explains the basics of safe MySQL data handling in PHP first of all please. Whatever place you got the idea from, that using `addslashes` was in any way the proper thing to do here, must have been a really crappy resource.

Comment: Thanks for the criticism CBroe, care to elaborate on a particular source that would be good for researching such improvements?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add connetion variable in you mysqli_query like this.

```
    mysqli_query(your connection variable,"INSERT INTO bnsf1 (offline, unit, commodity, shipper, origin, originState, current, currentState, estimatedArrival, carType, destination, destinationState, CP_dateTime, waybillNumber, equipmentLength) VALUES
        (
            '".addslashes($data[1])."',
            '".addslashes($data[2])."',
            '".addslashes($data[3])."',
            '".addslashes($data[4])."',
            '".addslashes($data[5])."',
            '".addslashes($data[6])."',
            '".addslashes($data[7])."',
            '".addslashes($data[8])."',
            '".addslashes($data[9])."',
            '".addslashes($data[10])."',
            '".addslashes($data[11])."',
            '".addslashes($data[12])."',
            '".addslashes($data[13])."',
            '".addslashes($data[14])."',
            '".addslashes($data[15])."'
        ) ");
```